# Google Sheet Script : This operation is not supported on a range with a filtered-out row

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, filter, google-sheets-api, filtered

Here is my issue :

My code below does not work because of the line: current.uncheck();

And the log say : "This operation is not supported on a range with a filtered-out row."

But this sheet is not supposed to contain a filter, I also try to remove the potential filters without success.

```
if(current.isChecked()) // If the check box is checked
{
  // I put some data in a array :
  var arraySupport = rangeColumnToArray(ss.getSheetByName("import_support").getRange("A1:A15"))

  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Copy of Data Bank");

  // I change criteria filter on other sheet :
  var criteriaSupport = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
      .setHiddenValues(arraySupport)
      .build();  
  dataSheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(24, criteriaSupport);
  
  ss.getRange("G5:G").clearContent();  // clear eventual content
  copyExo();  // This fonction copy one column from the filtered sheet (dataSheet) on activeSheet
  activeSheet.getFilter().remove();  // I try that without success
  current.uncheck(); // And I try to uncheck the checkbox
}
```

Thank's for all the help you will provide me.

Comment: Unfortunately, although I'm not sure about the relationship between `current` and the ranges which are used in the if statement, for example, in your situation, when `current.uncheck();` is put just before the line of `// I put some data in a array :`, is that the result you expect? If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: in fact, tanaike, your solution works, i could settle for that but i would like to understand the problem. Current is `var current = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell()` . the filtered data is in a sheet, I copy it to the current sheet. In fact the error seems to come from the fact that current is subjected to a filtering while on this sheet it seems that there is no filter

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Not sure how to do it, I voted for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure about the relationship between `current` and the ranges which are used in the if statement, in order to work `current.uncheck()`, I would like to propose the following modification.

#### Modified script:

```
if(current.isChecked()) // If the check box is checked
{
  current.uncheck();  // <--- "current.uncheck();" at the last line in this function is moved to here.
  // I put some data in a array :
  var arraySupport = rangeColumnToArray(ss.getSheetByName("import_support").getRange("A1:A15"))
```

#### Note:

- Although I'm not sure about the detail script of `copyExo()`, I think that in your script, if `current` is not changed in the script in your if statement, `current.uncheck()` at the last line works. For example, when you want to confirm about it, how about putting `if (current) console.log(current.getA1Notation())` at each line of script? By this, when the value of `current` is changed, you can see it at the log.